# How to search for an element and incase it does not exist search for another element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-except, selenium-webdriver-python

I'm trying to search for an element and if it doesn't exist search for another element, and here is my code:

```
try:
    elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath1')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath2")
    if elem.is_displayed():
        print('found 1st element')
        driver.quit()
    elif elem1.is_displayed():
        print('found 2nd element')
        driver.quit()
except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.quit()
        print('Error!')
```

but every time I get 'Error!', but when i try to find only one of the two elements it works properly.

Comment: Where in your code you are performing a search? Also if the search did not return anything what do you see on the UI?

Answer (score 3):

The entire logic to search for an element and if not ***visible*** search for another element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following code block:

```
try:
    elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='save' and text()='save']")))
    my_text = "Found 1st element"
except TimeoutException:
    elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='save' and text()='save']")))
    my_text = "Found 2nd element"
finally:
    print(my_text)
    driver.quit()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I think you also need to add this code: from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException otherwise the TimeoutException will be deemed undefined.